# What would be the regular expression to match the specific pattern string. i.e : 999x

Tags: c#, regex

I have the number in integer which can be anything from 1 to n.

Example : 1111, 9993, 9994, 99950, 9909

i have tried the expression "^999$" but that dosen't worked for me to match to pattern 999x only.

So finally, as a result i should be getting : 9993, 9994 as a valid match.
all the other should be ignored.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
(\b999\d),
```

Your matches will be saved to the capture group. If you only want `999x`, and not `999xx`, this is going to work because of the `,` at the end. Test it out here -> https://regex101.com/r/yU2oN0/2